# Where is 'Javascript Language Basic' config in VScode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I'd like to change the default snippet `log`, the description show it is assigned to `Javascript Language Basic`, but did not find the config file.

[image]

Comment: In my computer it's located at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\javascript\snippets\javascript.json` but since it's a program file it's probably a bad idea to edit it. No idea if there's a mechanism to override builtin snippets.

Comment: Related: [Cannot override/disable snippets defined in extensions](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10565)

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported as of VS Code 1.27.

Support for configuring the built-in snippets is tracked [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10565)